# How do you remove stubborn screws from a laptop?

Tags: laptop, screws

I am trying to remove the hard drive from a Sony Vaio laptop, which now fails to power on. I am having difficulty removing two of the four Phillips head screws, and I am beginning to strip the screw heads with a Phillips head screwdriver.

Although I see there are solutions for [removing screws with no heads](https://superuser.com/questions/758112/how-to-take-a-screw-out-of-my-laptop-casing-that-has-no-head), I imagine it should be easier to remove these somehow if the heads are still present.

What steps can I take to remove the stubborn screws, aside from applying more force?

[image: Stubborn screws.]

Comment: Once the heads have been stripped out, you can try cutting a slot in the head with a Dremel tool and use a flathead screwdriver.  If the head is still mostly intact, try putting a wide rubber band over the tip of the screwdriver and try again.  Also, there are special screwdrivers for removing screws with stripped heads.  They are hardened and have special cutting edges.  You tap it into place with a small hammer and it cuts a new matching indent in the head.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/602671/what-type-of-screw-drivers-should-i-use-to-service-my-laptop/602945#602945

Comment: Please be careful using tools having a powerful magnetic field near sensitive PC boards. I wiped a control board for a stationary bike like this. Maybe use a sheet of aluminum foil with a hole through which to get to the screw with a Dremel tool.

Answer (score 3):

If you're stripping the heads you're most likely using the wrong size screw  driver. You also may not have enough torque, which you can fix by using a longer screwdriver.

Comment: use a screwdriver with a bigger diameter

Comment: I have a bit holder that's shaped like an L. Does an awesome job at stuck screws.